# Последовательное чтение значений из списка в словарь

Tags: python, списки, словари

Здраствуйте. Есть готовый список, который содержит слова в определенной последовательности:

```
list = ['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be']
```

Требуется подсчитать частоту появления слов в этом списке и составить словарь, который содержит пары значений (слово) : (кол-во повторений этого слова).
Вот мой код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

list = ['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be']

counts = dict()
for word in list:
    if word not in counts: # Если символа нет в словаре, создаем новую запись
        counts[word] = 1
    else: # В противном случае инкрементируем d[c]
        counts[word] += 1

print counts
```

Подсчет слов ведется правильно. 
Проблема в том, что моя программа помещает новые записи в словарь **в хаотичном порядке**, а не так, как слова шли в предложении. Вот что интерпретатор выдает на выходе:

```
{'not': 1, 'To': 1, 'or': 1, 'to': 1, 'be': 2}
```

А должно быть так:

```
{'To': 1, 'be': 2, 'or': 1, 'not': 1, 'to': 1}
```

Как можно получить такой результат? Никак не могу монять.
P.S.: В Python я новичок, поэтому не судите строго.

Comment: Можно обойтись без if-else: counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы. Вопрос решен :)

Comment: Общее замечание: `list` -- это builtin имя в Питоне. Не нужно его использовать как своё имя, чтобы избежать путаницы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужен [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects), Dict не поддерживает упорядочивание записей по умолчанию.

Comment: Благодарю за наводку, буду разбираться :)

Answer (score 2):

Словарь в Питоне не обязан сохранять порядок добавления слов. Хотя некоторые реализации Питона, такие как Pypy, используют упорядоченные словари по умолчанию.

Чтобы подсчитать частоту появления слов во входном списке и напечатать их в том порядке как они заданы в списке, можно объединить `Counter` и `OrderedDict`, чтобы поддерживать порядок вставки:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

input_list = ['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be']
frequencies = OrderedCounter(input_list)
for item, count in frequencies.items():
    print("{}\t{}".format(item, count))
```

#### Результат

```
To  1
be  2
or  1
not 1
to  1
```

Если достаточно только напечатать результат, то можно обойтись только `Counter`, без `OrderedDict` или сортировки:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import Counter

input_list = ['To', 'be', 'or', 'not', 'to', 'be']
frequencies = Counter(input_list)
for item in input_list:
    count = frequencies.pop(item, None)
    if count is None:
        continue
    print("{}\t{}".format(item, count))
```

Результат совпадает с предыдущим кодом. `frequencies` словарь разрушается во время печати.

Answer (score 1):

Вот один вариант как отсортировать: [ссылка](http://pythoner.name/sortdict)

Comment: @Володимир Гончаров, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно просто отсортировать в алфавитном порядке, просто при выводе сделайте

```
for key in sorted(counts.keys()):
    print '{0}: {1}'.format(key, counts[key])
```

А если именно в том порядке, в котором они встречались в первый раз - да, как писал [Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/etki), используйте OrderedDict

Comment: Спасибо за удобный способ. Приму к сведению :)

Comment: Можно не sorted(counts.keys()), а просто sorted(counts) - отсортированный список и так попадут только ключи.